# android: adding an icon to the contacts list

Tags: android, icons, android-contacts

As part of an app, I'm trying to add an icon to every listing in the contacts list depending on the contact's information. Getting / parsing the information is no problem - now how do I actually insert the icon into the contact listing? Is it even possible?